# How to Upgrade Gmail for Google App Users

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

We had switched to Google Apps a year back and have been using the Gmail Google App since then. Recently, Google upgraded the look and feel of Gmail service and introduced new features like the integration of Buzz and most recent, Priority Inbox, but these features and additions are not availabe in Gmail Google Apps.

How do we upgrade the Gmail Google App to the latest version of Gmail? Do we have to go through some procedure to get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google generally does phased roll-outs, so you generally may not see everything when it is first released.  Roll-outs to GAFYD are generally later also.

However, Google differentiates between full release publishes and beta pre-release publishes.  By default, Google won't push pre-release features on you.  This is something the administrator for your domain will need to do.

[More information](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=82691)

> **Pre-release Features**
>
> By selecting this option, your users will be able to see and use new services and features at the same time as consumer users of Google's applications. We sometimes delay the launch of features like group chat and colored labels to Google Apps accounts because we want to ensure that all the features we bring to the Google Apps suite are useful and stable before providing them to our business, education and organizational users.
>
> To opt-in for pre-release features:
>
> 1. Log in to the Google Apps administrator control panel.
>      The URL is https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/primary-domain-name, where primary-domain-name is the domain name you used to sign up for Google Apps.
> 2. Click Domain settings.
> 3. Under the General tab, and in the New services and Pre-release Features section, check the box next to Enable pre-release features.
> 4. Click Save changes.
>
> Your users will have access to a new feature at the time of the initial launch, rather than when it rolls out to all Google Apps accounts. These features should be considered in testing for Google Apps, and we are unfortunately unable to offer support for these specific features.
>
> Please note that you can edit your selection in the future. It may take up to a day for the change to take effect in your users' accounts.

Comment: Link https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/primary-domain-name is showing an error "Not Found Error 404"

Comment: @chanchal1987, You're replacing *primary-domain-name* with the actual domain name you signed up with, right?